# Printing an NSDocument

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nsdocument, nsprintoperation

I'm trying to print a document. The document is an array of NSImageReps, or a single NSPDFImageRep, which has multiple pages. I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the NSPrintOperation class to print this.

The NSPrintOperation seems to need an NSView to print. Do I need to manually add each image into the view at a calculated position and then let it do the pagination? that seems like it isn't in the spirit of Cocoa... is there some technique that I'm missing?

Comment: I've posted a new solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Future reference, I believe the answer is PDFViews. you can add a PDFPage all at once to a PDFView (Via a PDFDocument) and then you can print with printWithInfo:autoRotate:

In theory at least, I have gotten the view created, and the print dialog comes up, but when I hit "print" the dialog doesn't disappear...

But that's a different question.

Answer (score 3):

Despite this having an accepted answer, it doesn't really answer the basic question, just gives a work-around.

I just had a similar problem (I have an array of objects each rendered by the same `NSView` subclass, one per page). Here's how I solved it, without the baroque nonsense of creating one giant view that holds all the pages...

1) We have an `NSView` subclass that has a model associated with it (`NSImage` in your case, `ModelData` in my case)

```
class BaseView: NSView {
    var modelData: ModelData /* Whatever your view needs to draw */
    //...
}
```

2) We have an array `var models: [ModelData]` in your document controller.

3) Create a new subclass that will be the printer view.

```
class PrinterView: BaseView {
    var pageIndex: Int = 1
    var modelArray: [ModelData]

    init(frame: NSRect, models: [ModelData]) {
        self.modelArray = models
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("invalid initializer")
    }

    override func knowsPageRange(_ range: NSRangePointer) -> Bool {
        range.pointee.location = 1
        range.pointee.length = self.modelArray.count
        return true
    }

    override func rectForPage(_ page: Int) -> NSRect {
        self.pageIndex = page
        return self.bounds
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        self.model = self.modelArray[self.page - 1] // Pages are 1, not 0, based
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
    }
} // That's it! That's all...
```

4) Do this in your document controller:

```
override func printOperation(withSettings printSettings: [String : Any]) throws -> NSPrintOperation {
    self.printInfo.horizontalPagination = .fitPagination
    self.printInfo.verticalPagination = .clipPagination
    let printView = PrinterView(size: self.printInfo.paperSize, models: self.models)

    return NSPrintOperation(view: printView, printInfo: self.printInfo)
}
```

Comment: This is a great easy solution, thanks! I edited the part with the initializers, which seems necessary to follow the swift rules about `init` and appease the compiler. The custom initializer should call `super`, and because we have a custom initializer, we are required to override the required initializer `init(coder:)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't print something that can't be drawn. NSView is how you draw what you want to print. You can make an NSView subclass just for printing that decides how you want the printing to work (e.g. do you want one NSImageRep for page — ANY size page?) by using NSView's pagination methods. Just override `knowsPageRange:` to return YES.

Comment: right, of course you can't print what you can't draw. But getting it to deal with multiple imageReps seems tedious. Is there a more elegant way of doing it than manually placing the images into a huge virtual view and then telling it where  each rectangle is manually? It seems, needlessly baroque...  Also, it is unclear what the point of knowsPageRange: is. what does it mean to know a page range?

Comment: You could use NSImageViews that automatically position the image, but you're going to have to specify how the document is drawn somehow. And `knowsPageRange:` tells the printing subsystem that you want to handle pagination yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**You can create view that that displays what you want to print. Then you use it to create print operation.**

You would typically created a view that displays your image. You implement an algorithm to figure out what image you want to display on which page. Then you return number of pages available to print and implement method to print specific page.

- If you have 10 images and you want to
  print one per page that's easy.
- If you want to print records per page
  and you have 100 records then you
  calculate how many records you can
  fit on a page (using current font
  size and number of lines per record).
- Then you figure out from records per
  page how many pages you need to
  display all records - this is your
  number of pages (range of pages).
- When requested to print specific
  range of pages you select the records
  that should be show on given page and
  display them.
- See references below on how to
  implement these steps. See [the
  custom pagination](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/Tasks/PaginatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000912) info for
  example how to implement these steps, it's not difficult.

See [Print Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/Printing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000083), or the full example I reference bellow from the book has pagination which I did not included here. Have a look at [the custom pagination](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/Tasks/PaginatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000912) for more hints.

If you have Document Based application and a view that you want to dump to printer, then in our `MyDocument` (or whatever you call it) that extends `NSDocument` you would implement:

```
- (NSPrintOperation *)printOperationWithSettings:(NSDictionary *)ps
                                           error:(NSError **)e
```

The view then uses standard `drawRect:` for drawing.

Example, here `PeopleView` just draws a `table` of people details, it takes a `NSDictonary` of people `employees` here:

```
- (NSPrintOperation *)printOperationWithSettings:(NSDictionary *)ps
                                           error:(NSError **)e
{
    PeopleView * view = [[PeopleView alloc] initWithPeople:employees];
    NSPrintInfo * printInfo = [self printInfo];
    NSPrintOperation * printOp
        = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:view
                                         printInfo:printInfo];
    [view release];
    return printOp;
}
```

You can look for more details in chapter 27, Printing, in Hillegass' Cocoa Programming For Mac OS X.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to have to do custom pagination. I just one one image per page, so I'd rather not have to manually place each image into the view at a specified location and then deal with that. I think the PDFView is much easier for what I want to do...